# Reciprocal Mean Value Property

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I'm kind of stuck on the following exercise:

Suppose $u \in C^2(\Omega)$. Given $x \in \Omega$, show that

\begin{align}
\Delta u(x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{2n}{r^2} \left[ \frac{1}{w_n} \int_{\partial B_{1}} u(x + ry)\mathrm{d}S_y - u(x) 
\right].
\end{align}

Conclude that from the above reciprocal expression of Mean Value Property.

We have a suggestion to solve it:

Consider Taylor's second-order polynomial of $u$ around $x$. Using symmetry, show that

\begin{align}
 \int_{\partial B_{1}} x_j \mathrm{d}S = \int_{\partial B_{1}} x_j x_k \mathrm{d}S = 0, \,\,\,\mathrm{para} \,\,\,j\neq k 
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
 \int_{\partial B_{1}} x_k^{2} \mathrm{d}S = n ^{-1}\int_{\partial B_{1}} \left[ 
 \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j^{2}\right] \mathrm{d}S = \int_{\partial B_{1}} 1 \mathrm{d}S.
\end{align}

Can anyone give me some help with this exercise?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If $u$ has Mean Value Property then RHS is $0$ so $u$ is harmonic. I don't quite understand what your question is. Can you tell us what you mean by reciprocal Mean Value Property?

Comment: I didn't get the point straight. It seems that he asks to use the limit to complete the Reciprocal Mean Value Property.
I would like to know how to resolve the limit and did not understand how to conclude with the Reciprocal. @KaviRamaMurthy